# function of "できる" in this example

Tags: grammar, translation

I have trouble understanding the function of "できる" in this example:

> 医療に応用できる究極の義体として作られたものだ

Is it used as "can" or "made from"?

Comment: Two big hints in the sentence: 1) 応用 is a 'suru-verb' 2) there is no particle between 応用 and できる

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used as "can".

Your example is translated as "It is made as an ultimate artificial human body which can be applied to medical use."